# How can I check if WAV audio file contains sound

Tags: android, makefile, path, wav

How can we know if a WAV file contains Audio or not in Android.

Is there any way in Android to find if a WAV file stored on SD contains audio.

Comment: What should it contain else?

Comment: Sometimes it contains silence.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am developing an app that detects sound, I record for the 3-second duration I check if the sound sample has a sound not silence then I compared it with other sounds